# Android API for BT LE

Tags: android, bluetooth

Does anybody have the idea when the official API for BT LE support is going to be released??
I have searched a lot but of no effect.
If any anybody is having the idea regarding when the android version for supporting the API for BT LE is going to be released,please share.
It will be of great help

Comment: As of now there is none. There's a Motorola API that only works on some Motorola devices and a thread on innovator.samsungmobile.com for the Galaxy S3 regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

You have BT-LE SDK available to download from Broadcom and Samsung.
http://code.google.com/p/broadcom-ble/

Comment: @OneWorld : BT LE is now officially available in android.  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html

Answer (score 0):

The SDK 18 code has the Google API now.

However, I am testing it and it is crashing on my Nexus 4.

The documentation is here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html